# Python Pandas Group by Column A and Sum Contents of Column B

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python panda data frame like:

```
    A    B
0  aa    4
1  bb    6
3  aa    12
4  bb    2
```

I want to group by Column A and sum values of column B. I am using the following code:

```
df.groupby(by=['A'])['B'].sum()
```

What I get is:

```
         B
    A    
0  aa    16
1  bb    14
```

But this is not exactly what i want, I want to get:

```
    A    B
0  aa    16
1  bb    14
```

So that i can access column A by `df['A']` or column B by `df['B']`.

How Can i get this? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `as_index=False` option:

```
In [34]: df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].sum()
Out[34]:
    A   B
0  aa  16
1  bb   8
```

By default, pandas will set the column you use to group by as the index. You can also always so a `reset_index` afterwards.

Comment: 9 secs quicker than me, and a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby('A').sum().reset_index()
Out[7]: 
    A   B
0  aa  16
1  bb   8
```

Then access `'A'` for example:

```
In [8]: df.groupby('A').sum().reset_index()['A']
Out[8]: 
0    aa
1    bb
```